# JQUERY Mobile form jumps on inputting values

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile

I have this really annoying issue with the form jumping up and down on inputting values.  I am using Jquery mobile version 1.0.1 using phonegap and testing it out on android 2.3 (this issue is only on android and not on iphones -why!?) .

I noticed that if the page is not scrolled before focussing on input box, then there is no issue. But the moment I scroll the page, and click on text box to input value , all hell breaks loose. Can anyone please enlighten me what is going on! Thanks in advance

Comment: adding this line - android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" - to the main activity in the android manifest fixed the bouncing, but now the form fields below are not visible as it gets covered by the android keyboard!

Comment: I have similar issue If I found any solution I let you update

Answer (score 2):

I solved my issue as follows:

The container div have following css:

```
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0,0,0.25,1);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

Removing it solved my problem in android.

It seems android is buggy with advanced css3 styles.

Hope this information may help...